# Problem with .out files using Texshop

Tags: texshop, large-files

I am using tex-shop for tex-ing files locally on my mac. Recently, whenever I resolved a grammatical/compiling error and try to recompile it, the complier console always told me that there is a problem with my .out file

.out:16: Undefined control sequence.
l.16 \BO

even tho there is nothing wrong with my main tex file. I will only be able to recompile it after manually deleting the .out file. Usually, this type of situation won't happen when my tex file is a small one, but it becomes really frequent as my tex file grows larger and larger. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: `out` files mosly consist of multiple calls to a command `\BOOKMARK`  so I would guess that after an error you are not letting TeX exit cleanly (eg wih `x`) but are killing the process (eg killing the editor window) so the files being written are not correctly flushed so leave half written commands that error on the next run.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How should I fix this? and why such error do not occur on a smaller file but happens so frequently with large files. In addition, what you do mean by (eg wih x)?

Comment: delete the broken `.out` file and try again. And next time you get an error type the letter `x` on your keyboard and hit enter. Then tex can exit more cleanly.

Comment: Many Thanks to David and Ulrike! It worked very well!